# How do i get all public pages in DotNetNuke?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am new to DNN web sites, and would like to display a list of the root level pages (Home, Contact Us, etc..) at the top of my skin.  Right now I have:

```
TabController.GetPortalTabs(0,-1, false, "", false, false, false, true,false);
```

Feeding my repeater which displays the links.  However, when I am logged in to edit the pages, the navigation grows to include all admin level pages as well and breaks my design.  Is there a way to get just the public pages to show even when I am logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the help from above to get here:

```
List<DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabInfo> tabs = TabController.GetTabsByParent(-1, 0).FindAll(
         delegate(DotNetNuke.Entities.Tabs.TabInfo tab)
         {
             return tab.IsVisible && !tab.IsDeleted;
         }
        );
```

Answer (score 11):

You could use var tabs = TabController.GetTabsByParent(-1, PortalId);

Then you could filter through that list of tabs to remove any that aren't displayed in the menu. Something like the following.

```
var tabs = TabController.GetTabsByParent(-1, PortalId);
            foreach (var t in tabs)
            {
                if (t.IsVisible)
                {
                    Response.Write(t.TabName);
                    Response.Write("<br />");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Nice, did not see the isVisible property first time around, I used your help to get me to my final answer posted below.

Comment: DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.GetPortalTabs(portalID, false, true, false, true, true)  .. this is my function it return a array list with all tabs .. but i don't want Admin tabs ... What to do?  please help me..

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of Linq makes is nice and clean

```
Dim pages = (From tc In TabController.GetTabsByParent(-1, PortalId)
             Where tc.IsVisible And Not tc.IsDeleted
             Select tc).ToList
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to also check if the page was deleted or I was getting zombie pages to show up.

```
var tabs = TabController.GetTabsByParent(-1, PortalId);
        foreach (var t in tabs)
        {
            if (t.IsVisible && !t.IsDeleted)
            {
                Response.Write(t.TabName);
                Response.Write("<br />");
            }
        }
```

Comment: DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.GetPortalTabs(portalID, false, true, false, true, true)  .. this is my function it return a array list with all tabs .. but i don't want Admin tabs ... What to do?  please help me..